# How to query HasMany Association based on single value in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.x, querying

I have an Articles table and a Comments Table.
Articles Has Many Comments.
Each Comment Belongs to a Comment Status (comment_status_id):
    1. Good, or
    2. Bad, or
    3. Ugly.

I want to make a query to find all the Articles that have ONLY Comments with status 3 (Ugly).  That is, exclude Articles that have any Comments with status 1 or 2.

I can write a subquery and query to get all the Article that have a comment with Status Ugly:

```
$matchingComments = $this->Articles->getAssociation('Comments')->find()
    ->select(['article_id'])
    ->distinct()
    ->where(['comment_status_id' => 3]);

$query = $this->Articles->find()
    ->where(['Articles.id IN' => $matchingComments]);
```

This gives me all the Articles that have any Comment that has status 3.  But it also includes Articles that have Comments with status 2 or 1 in addition at least one Comment with status 3.

So my question is:
Is there an efficient/elegant way to make this query work with the Query Builder so the result is only Articles that have Comments that are ALL comment_status 3 (Ugly)?

I'm sure I can parse the $query results with a for loop and build a new array of results, but I would like to see if there is a better way to do this in the initial query and/or/with subquery.
Thanks in advance for any advice!

D.

Comment: Do you know how to do it in raw SQL? It's always best to figure that out first.

Comment: Thanks ndm.... yes, that is the right approach to solving the question.  I'll add my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Following ndm's advice to get the raw sql to work first, this query worked for my matchingComments query

```
SELECT `article_id`
FROM `comments`
GROUP BY `article_id`
HAVING MIN(`comment_status_id`) = 3
AND MAX(`comment_status_id`) = 3;
```

So then in my Cake controller, this works:

```
$matchingComments = $this->Articles->getAssociation('Comments')->find()
    ->select(['article_id'])
    ->group('article_id')
    ->having(['MIN(comment_status_id)' => 3])
    ->having(['MAX(comment_status_id)' => 3])

$query = $this->Articles->find()
    ->where(['Articles.id IN' => $matchingComments]);
```

Not sure if there is a better way, but this works nicely.
Thanks again ndm.
D.

Answer (score 0):

From [Cake Book - Retrieving Data & Results Sets](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data-via-matching-and-joins)

```
$articles = $this->Articles
    ->find()
    ->contain(['Comments'])
    ->notMatching('Comments.CommentStatus', function($q) {
        return $q->where(['CommentStatus.comment_status_id' => '3'];
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis.  This approach produces a list of all Articles with comments that are not status 3, and lists them by comment, so multiple repetitions of the same article_id int he list, so not the goal.  Anyway, I'll play around with combinations of matching and notMatching and see that works. Thanks.

Comment: Just try put "notMatching" to static function inside contain like **'Comments' => static function ($q) = {return $q->notMatching.....};**